# Implement #absolute_path for Pathname child

Tags: ruby, oop

An instance of [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Pathname.html) is a pretty useful object because of all the great messages it responds to.

For example, even if the path doesn't exist it can tell you if it's an absolute path:

```
some_path = Pathname.new("/some/nonexistent/path")
p some_path.absolute?
#=> true
```

It can given you the "absolute_path" using the method `realpath` if the path already exists on disk:

```
another_path = Pathname.new("some/existing/path")
p another_path.realpath
#=> #<Pathname:/Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/abs_path/some/existing/path>
```

But if the path doesn't exist already `realpath` breaks:

```
yet_another_path = Pathname.new("some/nonexistent/path")
p yet_another_path.realpath
# `realpath': No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/abs_path/some/nonexistent (Errno::ENOENT)
```

So I'm trying to implement another class called `SomeDir` that inherits from `Pathname` and responds to the `absolute_path` message with the "absolute path if it existed". I don't think this is too weird since it's sort of like calling `to_s` on the original nonexistent Pathname, except it's giving the absolute_path.

This is my implementation:

```
require 'pathname'
require 'fileutils'

class SomeDir < Pathname

  attr_reader :cwd_on_instantiation 
  def initialize path
    @cwd_on_instantiation = Dir.pwd 
    super
  end

  def absolute_path
    if exist?
      Pathname.new(to_s).realpath
    elsif absolute?
      Pathname.new(to_s)
    else
      Pathname.new(File.join(cwd_on_instantiation, to_s)) 
    end
  end
end

some_dir = SomeDir.new("some/nonexistent/path")
p some_dir.absolute_path
# #<Pathname:/Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/abs_path/some/nonexistent/path>
```

So it seems like it works.

Now, I'm wondering:

1. Are there any cases where you can see this not working as expected?
2. How would I re-implement the `absolute_path` method if without the `if...elsif..else` block?
3. What would a better name for the `cwd_on_instantiation` instance variable be?

Edit:

Thank you @coreyward for the code example. It seems like it isn't working when I `chdir` though:

```
require 'pathname'
require 'fileutils'
include FileUtils

class FileResolver
  BASE_DIR = Dir.pwd.freeze

  attr_reader :filepath
  def initialize(filepath)
    @filepath = filepath
  end

  def absolute_path
    Pathname.new(BASE_DIR).join(filepath)
  end
end

chdir "some" do 
  puts Dir.pwd # /Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/freeze_example/some
  yet_another_dir = FileResolver.new('nonexistent')
  p yet_another_dir.absolute_path
  #=> #<Pathname:/Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/freeze_example/nonexistent>
end
```

Not sure why `Dir.pwd.freeze` isn't picking up the `chdir "some"`

Comment: Because `chdir` is occurring after `Dir.pwd` has been fetched, tagged as frozen, and assigned to `FileResolver::BASE_DIR`. That's what it sounded like you wanted. You are welcome to change `FileResolver` to accept a path you pass it. In any case, I would avoid `chdir` and instead use more explicit paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get a faux-realpath for files that don't exist? If so, you might be better served by using `.join` and handing in the necessary components:

```
Pathname.new(Dir.pwd).join("some/nonexistent/path")
```

If you have a file that exists, but your path string is a fragment and you need to provide another base directory to `realpath`, you can do that too:

```
path = Pathname.new('/path/and/file.jpg')
path.realpath('some/existing')
#=> '/some/existing/path/and/file.jpg'
```

An example implementation might be…

```
class FileResolver
  BASE_DIR = Dir.pwd.freeze

  def initialize(filepath)
    @filepath = filepath
  end

  def absolute_path
    Pathname.new(BASE_DIR).join(@filepath)
  end
end
```

Or, if your files aren't relative to this class but instead your Rails project, a better way is to use `Rails.root.join`:

```
Rails.root.join('your/path', 'some/filename.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Didn't know that about `join` or `realpath`. I think the problem with your solution is although it eliminates the instance variable it returns the `Dir.pwd` on method invocation instead of on instance creation. I'm not sure if this is a big deal in practice but I was able to `chdir` after instantiation in a minitest test which caused `absolute_path` to give the wrong path.

Comment: @mbigras You wouldn't want to call it on each trip through the codebase anyways, so definitely abstract that away however makes sense given your architecture.

Comment: Sorry @coreyward, I'm a little confused. I wouldn't want to call my way or your way? And also what do you mean by "abstract it away"? Are you saying, yes keep doing it my way because it abstracts away the need to know about what directory I'm in when I invoke the `SomeDir#absolute_path` method?

Comment: @mbigras I added an example; hopefully that'll help.